# How do I keep a specific xaml element within the window (so it doesn't overflow through the bottom)

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to make a simple invoicing application as part of an assessment. I have made a interface with a listbox that contains all the items that have been requested. However when I add too many items, the listbox then flows through the bottom of the window and I have to resize the window to fit.

I've tried a dockpanel, and I've assigned the stackpanel to the grid itself.  If I set a fixed height it seems to work as expected.

Here is the xaml of the listbox:

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ClipToBounds="True">
        <ListBox Name="Shirts" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="5" ClipToBounds="True">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding ShirtSize}" />
                        <Run Text="{Binding ShirtStyle}" />
                        <Run Text="{Binding ShirtColour}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Print Invoice" Margin="5" ClipToBounds="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

I expected the code to work like this (it's not meant to be of fix height but it works as an example).

[image: GUI that is meant to work.]
How it actually works.
[image: How it actually works.]

Comment: Is it me or are both attached images the same?

Comment: The `ListBox` as many other wpf controls will resize self based on its content as much as **parent container allows** unless you set its `Width` and/or `Height`. To dynamically limit height you can bind `ListBox.Height` (or `MaxHeight`) to some other element  `ActualHeight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DockPanel instead of a StackPanel and it should work better. StackPanel will grow with its content regardless of its container size. A DockPanel will respect the container size and fill the available space. Put the button first in order with Dock="Bottom" and then the ListBox with Dock="Fill" (the list will arrange itself above the button even though it is declared after it, which is a bit unintuitive)